# django If don't have a model, Redirect to createview. If there is, I would like to do it in detail view

Tags: python, django

```
class KcalDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'target_kcal'
    template_name = 'kcalculatorapp/detail.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.kcal:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('kcalculatorapp:create'))
        return super(KcalDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`model.py`

```
class Kcal(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kcal', null=True)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='',  null=False , verbose_name='height')
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='',  null=False, verbose_name='weight')
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='',  null=False, verbose_name='age')
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

If you go into the detail view,

`User has no kcal.` error

That's what it says
What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUON5.png)

Comment: Have you made custom your model? As inbuilt `User` model has no field `kcal`.

Comment: yes!! custom model  class Kcal(models.Model):

Comment: Share that model.

Comment: question add model.py!!

Comment: But you mentioned `model=User` in view. You should mention `Kcal` model I think.

Comment: Have you made custom `User` model through `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser`?

Comment: Since I'm trying,

''' No kcal matching query found. '''

Comment: Create a user separately from the create view.!  createview add pic

Comment: i try this 
 if not self.request.user.kcal : 
>> if not self.request.user

Since I opened the kcal in the back,
What's the reason for doing well?

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if you would have kcal field on User linking your User to Kcal. If you are trying to get object with one to one relation by related name in Django and object does not exist, ObjectDoesNotExist exception is raised. What you should do is embed your redirect in try ... except... block like that:

```
try:
    self.request.user.kcal:
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('kcalculatorapp:create'))
```

Of course you could do Kcal.ObjectDoesNotExist but i don't know your project structure if it would not cause circle import error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should override the `get` method instead of the dispatch `method` and use `getattr` to check for a `Kcal` relation.

```
class KcalDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not getattr(self.request.user, 'kcal', None):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('kcalculatorapp:create'))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And since you are relying on authentication rather than url kwargs to determine the object to return, you need to override the `get_object` method as well.

```
class KcalDetailView(DetailView):
    ...

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user.kcal
```

So your final view should look something like this:

```
class KcalDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'target_kcal'
    template_name = 'kcalculatorapp/detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user.kcal

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not getattr(self.request.user, 'kcal', None):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('kcalculatorapp:create'))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```